# Bootstrap 3 Carousel selecting certain divs, a custom setup

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a tricky situation. I have content that is dynamically populated that I want to lay out in the Bootstrap 3 carousel. The catch is, out of that dynamic string, only 3/4s of it should go in the carousel. Here is a brief example

```
<?php if ($imagePosition == 'left'): ?>
    <div class="hero-item item no-carousel">
        Conent I don't want to be shown on the carousel
    </div>
    <div class="hero-item item show">
        I want this to be shown in the carousel
    </div>
<?php elseif ($imagePosition == "background"): ?>
    <div class="hero-item item show">
        I want this to be shown in the carousel
    </div>
<?php elseif ($imagePosition == "right"): ?>
    <div class="hero-item item show">
        I want this to be shown in the carousel
    </div>
    <div class="hero-item item no-carousel">
        Conent I don't want to be shown on the carousel
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

So the output could be

```
<div class="hero-item item no-carousel">Content I don't want to be shown on the carousel</div>
<div class="hero-item item show">I want this to be shown in the carousel</div>
<div class="hero-item item show">I want this to be shown in the carousel</div>
<div class="hero-item item no-carousel">Conent I don't want to be shown on the carousel</div>
```

How can I get the Bootstrap carousel to just show the items that I want to show, for example, the ones with the class 'show'?

Comment: So you want static content on the left and right of a carousel?  Also, I think you need to remove the bootstrap tag from your question.  That tag refers to bootstrap procedures run on the server at start up (it specifically says: NOT to be confused with Twitter Bootstrap in the description).

Comment: How about simply applying `display:none` for whatever you don't want to show..?

Comment: Applying display none still renders a blank spot unfortunately

Comment: jme11, sorry if I wasn't clear. All of content has to go in the carousel, I just can't show certain divs within that carousel

Comment: @TilwinJoy I essentially used .no-carousel {display:none!important;} and that didn't work, there was a blank spot, the carousel still tried to place 'active' class on it.

Comment: "All of content has to go in the carousel, I just can't show certain divs within that carousel." Say wha??

Comment: @isherwood jme11 was asking if I wanted content outside of the carousel, on the left and right from what I got out of it. Looking back at my response I was probably staring at a screen for 10+hrs and my brain misfired :P. I just meant that the HTML all had to reside within the 'carousel-inner' div that Bootstrap requires, including the divs I didn't want to show

Comment: That's what I thought you meant. The confusion is about why you'd need that. It would require modifying the Bootstrap plugin or some convoluted move-them-out, move-them-back-in process. And it's just weird. :-)

Comment: @isherwood I would need that because the content is generated dynamically and not all of it is needed in the carousel. It is odd, I agree, I just wanted to avoid rewriting the dynamic part that adds the HTML that eventually gets plopped in the carousel

Comment: I'm still not getting myself across here. :-) You can either 1) remove the elements that shouldn't be in the carousel, 2) move those elements elsewhere in the page, or 3) clone those elements that should be in the carousel and add them elsewhere. You cannot run the carousel with the extra elements in place.